# Translator Trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, input

This is how the webpage looks like http://prntscr.com/5o16hz

I've created an onclick function for the 'generate romaji' button that checks if 'vowels' or 'all columns' is checked, and then displays random romaji characters in the div right under the 'generate romaji' button.

The problem is, it isn't working and i'm not sure why.

```
var vowel = document.getElementById("vowels");
//'vowel' var is for the 'vowels' checkbox//
var allhiragana = document.getElementById("all");
//'allhiragana' var is for the 'all columns' checkbox//
var genDiv = document.getElementById("romaji");
var showDiv = document.getElementById("hiragana");
var fullromaji = ['a','i','u','e','o',"ka","ki","ku""ke","ko","sa",'shi','su','se','so',
"ta","chi","tsu","te","to","na","ni","nu","ne","no","ha","hi","fu","he","ho","ma","mi",
"mu","me","mo","ya","yu","yo","ra","ri","ru","re","ro",
"wa","wo"];     
var fullhiragana = ['あ','い','う','え','お','か','き','く','け','こ','さ','し','す','せ','そ',    
'た','ち' 'つ','て','と','な','に','ぬ','ね','の','は','ひ','ふ','へ','ほ','ま','み','む','め','も',
'や','ゆ','よ','ら','り','る''れ','ろ','わ','ゐ','ゑ','を'];
//first random factor//
var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * fullromaji.length);
//second random factor//
var h = Math.floor(Math.random() * fullromaji.length);
//button functions//
var genromaji = function() {
    if(vowel.prop('checked')){
        fullromaji = ["a",'i','u','e','o'];
        fullhiragana = ['あ','い','う','え','お'];
        genDiv.innerHTML = fullromaji[r];
        showDiv.innerHTML = fullhiragana[r];
        showDiv.text().hide();
        }
    if(allhiragana.prop('checked')) {
        fullromaji = ["ka","ki","ku","ke","ko","sa",'shi','su','se','so',
"ta","chi","tsu","te","to","na","ni","nu","ne","no","ha","hi","fu","he","ho","ma","mi",
"mu","me","mo","ya","yu","yo","ra","ri","ru","re","ro",
"wa","wo"]; 
        fullhiragana = ['あ','い','う','え','お','か','き','く','け','こ','さ','し','す','せ','そ',    
'た','ち','つ','て','と','な','に','ぬ','ね','の','は','ひ','ふ','へ','ほ','ま','み','む','め','も',
'や','ゆ','よ','ら','り','る''れ','ろ','わ','ゐ','ゑ','を'];
    genDiv.innerHTML = fullromaji[h];
    showDiv.innerHTML = fullhiragana[h];
    showDiv.text().hide();
    }
    else {
    alert("please check one box before generating Romaji");
};
var showhiragana = function() {
    if(getDiv.text() === typeof('string')) {
        showDiv.text().show();
    }
    else {
    alert("Please generate the Romaji first");
    }
};
```

The 'genDiv' is the div that is under the 'generate romaji' button, and its inner text should be a random string from the 'fullromaji' array, and the showDiv is the div under the 
'show hiragana' button that shows the corresponding hiragana from the 'fullhiragana' array.

I'm not sure if the problem is the code itself, or maybe its the way I linked it in the html, which, for the sake of reading this question, is shorted but still visible in this printscreen

http://prntscr.com/5o1eb9

Comment: could you please post a fiddle for us..

Comment: whya are you doing `vowel.prop('checked')`???try  checking it like `if (vowel.checked)`..

Comment: @Lal                                                                  here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0eg10fbe/                        I already tried (vowel.checked) but that didn't work either. And I put the javascript in <script> tags because it was originally external and saved locally and js fiddle can't load local js...

Comment: There are some syntax errors in the arrays (missing comma) `"ku""ke"` `'ち' 'つ'`

Comment: JavaScript identifiers are case sensitive. You define `fullromaji` but use `fullRomaji.length`.

Comment: @RolandJansen i fixed both of those and its still not working         http://jsfiddle.net/alienc/0eg10fbe/7/

Comment: @AlienC Oh my, you have got a whole lot of other syntax errors. You should open the javascript console in your browser to make sure that you at least do not have any syntax errors before you post a question. Here, fixed as much errors as I could: http://jsfiddle.net/json/0eg10fbe/9/

Comment: @0x2D9A3 oh, i see, i forgot to load jquery into the jsfiddle and a couple of other things, thanks!

Comment: @0x2D9A3 sometimes, the generate romaji button returns 'undefined' and i'm not sure why.I found somebody with a similar problem, and tried the solution given to them, but it did not work. http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/255942-why-does-it-sometimes-display-undefined/